# Change ViewPager's overscroll color

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-theme

How can I change the overscroll glow effect color of a ViewPager in android? Or is there a way to change the overscroll color for the whole app via themes?

I know of setOverScrollHeader and footer, but these does "logically" of course not work for a viewpager in horizontal mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally found a solution!!**

A great library by [AndroidAlliance](https://github.com/AndroidAlliance) called [EdgeEffectOverride](https://github.com/AndroidAlliance/EdgeEffectOverride).

It easily allows changing the overscroll color of ScrollView, ListView, ExpandableListView, GridView & **ViewPager**

Link: https://github.com/AndroidAlliance/EdgeEffectOverride

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do it is to override `colorPrimary` for your viewpager using themes.

For example :

In your fragment/activity :

```
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Viewpager" />
```

In your file `styles.xml` :

```
<style name="AppTheme.Viewpager" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 : You could call inside the scroll listener the methods setBackground, setBackgroundColor and setAlpha methods to create your own appearance.

Solution 2 : You could create your own AlphaAnimation that it will be triggered inside the scroll listener.

```
    AlphaAnimation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation( 0.0f , 1.0f ) ; 
    fadeIn.setDuration(1000);

    yourViewPager.startAnimation(fadeIn);
```

Comment: hm,okay. Thanks although it doesn't really sound like a very clean solution.